# Unusual Perl Syntax

Tags: perl

I have to make modifications to a Perl script, and this is my first attempt at understanding Perl. I see the following:

```
my %trades;
...
foreach my $row (@$rows) {
  @{$trades{pop @$row}} = @$row;
}
```

I am confused by this because it appears that we are popping off the last item in the array `@$row` and setting the hash key of `%trades` to be the item that was popped off and setting the value to be `@$row`.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Just a style note: it's typically "Perl" for the language, and "perl" for the program.  It's not "PERL" unless your shift key is stuck.  :)

Comment: Could also be written `$trades{pop @$row} = $row;` or `my $id = pop @$row; $trades{$id} = $row;`

Comment: @ikegami: No. Because yours copies references whereas the original copies array elements.

Comment: @Borodin, That's the whole point. Why make needless copies. (They're already clobbering @$row as a side-effect.)

Comment: @ikegami: Then your *"Could also be written"* is misleading without a qualification. The modification of the rows may be deliberate.

Comment: @ikegami: affecting, not clobbering

Comment: @ysth, hum? What do you mean? Data is being extracted from `$rows` in a fashion that destroys it. That's the very definition of clobbering.

Comment: @ikegami: no, only the first element of each array is removed; there is plenty of data not destroyed.

Comment: @ysth, I ?now. ?ut I ?oubt ?ou ?ould ?ay ?his ?entence ?asn't ?een ?estroyed.

Comment: @ikegami: the fact of the shallow copy makes me suspect at least the possibility that there is further use of $rows

Comment: @ysth, ...or that someone didn't know better. What you say is a possibility, but I find it very unlikely. It's hard to believe that they'd remove the row's key on purpose. Looks more like a format translation. I've encountered this anti-pattern in newcomers many times.

Comment: And if you're right, it's not like the breaking will be subtle.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To understand that piece of code, we need to be clear of three things:

- *Evaluation order:*

  ```
  EXPR_A = EXPR_B
  ```

  evaluates `EXPR_B` before evaluating `EXPR_A`.
- *Copying semantics:*

  ```
  @new_array = @old_array
  ```

  copies the values of `@old_array` over to `@new_array`.
- *Dereferencing of complex data structures:*

  ```
  @{ $trades{$key} }
  ```

  accesses the entry called `$key` in the `%trades` hash, and treats it as an array reference.

Together, your code is equivalent to this:

```
foreach my $row (@$rows) {
  my @copy = @$row;
  my $key = pop @$row;
  @{ $trades{$key} } = @copy;
}
```

(while preserving all side effects I can see)

So for example

```
$rows = [
  [1, 2, "keyA"],
  [3, 4, "keyB"],
];
```

would create

```
%trades = (
  keyA => [1, 2, "keyA"],
  keyB => [3, 4, "keyB"],
);
$rows = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];
```

Whoever wrote that line had very precise knowledge about evaluation order and loves to torture maintenance programmers.

Comment: specifically, it appears to be filling `%trades` with a copy of each row from `@rows`, where the key for each entry is the value of the last column of that row.

Comment: I would have +1000 for you if I could for your last comment alone.

Comment: Whoever wrote that code may know Perl, but doesn't know much about good software development practices. And one of the multitude of idiots that gave Perl such an awful reputation that most companies refuse to use it.

Comment: I think it's far more likely that the author wanted to use the last element of each array as a key for the rest, and didn't expect that the `pop` wouldn't remove that key. As it stands the assignment would be better written as `@{$trades{$row->[-1]}} = @$row` and `pop` is superfluous except that it changes the stuff in `$rows`.

Comment: I don't know - this can be perfectly acceptable if `$rows` is a short-lived temporary variable in a tight scope.

Comment: Perhaps he wanted `keyA => [1, 2]` and `keyB => [3, 4]` instead, i.e. with the key removed from the array. I mean, you don't usually have one of the elements to be the same as the key, do you?

Answer (score 3):

The loop is equivalent to

```
my %trades = map { $_->[-1] => [ @$_ ] } @$rows
```

except that this way `@$rows` remains unmodified. IMO it should be written that way.

Comment: Except the last element for each row in $rows is lost in the original code.